# Is the Absence of Account deletion possibility legal in Europe? (GDPR)

Tags: gdpr

This [website](https://support.mindbodyonline.com/s/article/217734897-Can-I-delete-my-account?language=en_US#:%7E:text=There%20is%20not%20a%20way,retain%20for%20record%20keeping%20purposes.) explicitly states there is no easy way to "delete your account". It is accessible from within Europe.

- How legal is this?
- What would be my lever to force them to delete my account?

Note on context: I actually came across the problem not because of any misuse of my data, but because this extremely buggy app seems to not work correctly for some people having created their account from the web rather than the phone app. I hence thought of deleting everything and then recreating it from the phone... But could not.

- [https://support.mindbodyonline.com/s/article/217734897-Can-I-delete-my-account?language=en_US#:~:text=There%20is%20not%20a%20way,retain%20for%20record%20keeping%20purposes](https://support.mindbodyonline.com/s/article/217734897-Can-I-delete-my-account?language=en_US#:%7E:text=There%20is%20not%20a%20way,retain%20for%20record%20keeping%20purposes).

Comment: The GDPR right to erasure / to be forgotten only applies in comparatively limited circumstances and has many exceptions. You do not mention any valid reason in your question, so it looks perfectly fine that deleting an account is not possible.

Comment: Humm, I thought one could just by right ask for deletion of any personal data? this is not the case ?

Comment: @user2346536 as the other commenter noted, only in certain circumstances - https://gdpr-info.eu/art-17-gdpr/

Comment: There are two separate issues at hand: closing your account, and deleting your data. Refusing to close the account seems problematic but is not directly about the GDPR. When the account is closed it seems a right to erasure would apply per GDPR Art 17(1)(a), although they would be allowed to keep some data such as invoices. They are not required to offer automated means for deleting your data, so you'll have to use their support channels

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question well enough I guess :)